# No change to mask when parent's source text size changes

Tags: after-effects

I have two mask layers, each whose 'Parent' is a type layer. When I change the Scale of the type layer, the mask layer adjusts its size proportionately, but when I change the size of the type using the Source Text parameter the mask does not react. Is it possible for the mask to change size at the same time the size of the Source Text does?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Normally linking one parameter to another is fairly easy with expressions, but in this case the *Source Text* property only returns the text content; all of the style information like the font size isn't accessible. Is there a reason why you're animating the font size rather than the scale of the layer?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wanted the change in text size to be immediate, instead of over time via keyframes, although I put the keyframes 1 frame apart and it achieves the same thing.

Comment: Right click on the keyframe and choose **Toggle Hold Keyframe** that turns it into a hold keyframe that doesn't interpolate: i.e. it stays the same until it hits the next keyframe and then changes instantly. Saves a lot of mucking about with one-frame-apart keyframes.